# Is there a paper that explains Kasparov's KK theory in English?

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory, k-theory, topological-k-theory, mathematical-russian

I need to learn Kasparov's KK theory but the original paper is written in Russian.

*G.G. KASPAROV, The operator K-functor and extensions of C*-algebras, Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR,
Ser. Mat. 44 (1980), 571-636 Math. USSR Izv. 16 (1981), 513-572.*

Does anyone know where I can find it's English version?

Comment: Is this Garry Kasparov?

Comment: Nope.  Gennadii.

Comment: No.  It is Gennadii Georgievich Kasparov rather than Garry Kimovich Kasparov

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Gennadi Kasparov https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KK-theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

Mathematics of the USSR-Izvestiya, Volume 16, Number 3

G G Kasparov 1981 Math. USSR Izv. 16 513

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/IM1981v016n03ABEH001320

The original Russian version is Izv. Akad. Nauk SSSR Ser. Mat., 1980, Volume 44,    Issue 3,    Pages 571–636 http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=1739&option_lang=eng

Comment: Oh I thought it was the Russian one. Thank you.